# Abnormal delay while starting execution of async Task method C#

Tags: c#, async-await, task

On timer elapsed I am calling an async method at every 1.5 seconds.

In the log file I can see time difference of 300ms between start of TimerElapsed and SendMessage method.

i.e. between "OnTimerElapsed : started" and "SendMessage: started".

Although it happens rarely after windows services runs for an entire day.

```
private async void OnTimerElapsed(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    SourceTrace.TraceVerbose("OnTimerElapsed : started");
    await SendMessage();
    SourceTrace.TraceVerbose("OnTimerElapsed : completed");         
}

public async Task SendMessage()
{
    SourceTrace.TraceVerbose("SendMessage: started");

    var sendTask = Send(); // start sending
    var getTask = GetData(); // update data
    await Task.WhenAll(sendTask, getTask);
}
```

How can I get rid of such unusual high delay of 300-600ms occurring rarely and randomly?

- I also tried running windows service as 'High Priority' process.
- .Net framework version is 4.7.1

**Update**:
SourceTrace.TraceVerbose is wrapper on System.Diagnostics TraceSource and TextWriterTraceListener. It usually takes 1-2 ms to write the log.

Comment: You didn't post the asynchronous code.  The `TraceVerbose` methods execute *synchronously*. What do `Send()` and `GetData()` do? Simply returning a `Task` doesn't make a method asynchronous

Comment: `async` doesn't make a method run asynchronously. It's syntactic sugar that allows the compiler to use the `await` keyword to await *already* asynchronous operations to complete without blocking. `SendMessage` will run on the same thread as `SourceTrace.TraceVerbose("OnTimerElapsed : started");` and only yield when `await Task.WhenAll()` is encountered. If the `Send()` and `GetData()` methods don't do something really asynchronous, they'll run synchronously too.

Comment: GetData is fetching data from DB using EF6. Send is writing to serial port. Task.Run is used for the write operation.

Comment: It could be that the event handler takes so much time that logs from one run are mixed with the other. Or it could be that SourceTrace (which isn't a .NET BCL class) batches events. The question's code though doesn't start any tasks, so there's no way to say what could be wrong

Comment: @DeveshS post the code. The code you posted doesn't start any tasks. It's more likely that the log messages got mixed.

Comment: @Sinatr we haven't seen the actual log records, and the code runs *synchronously* up to that point. The only things that run up to that point are... the two consecutive `TraceVerbose` calls

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, yeah, my bad. The delay has something to do with `TraceVerbose`.

Comment: @DeveshS post the *SourceTrace.TraceVerbose* code. There are no tasks involved in the question, just two consecutive *synchronous* calls to `SourceTrace.TraceVerbose`. The 300ms delay is caused by those two calls. Since this is a custom class, I suspect it's not as efficient as the built-in TraceSource or the most common logging libraries like Serilog, NLog or log4net. Perhaps it's trying to write directly to a file, instead of separating the trace source from the actual listeners/sinks? Or perhaps it takes extra time to retrieve verbose details like the environment, stack trace etc?

Comment: It is a wrapper on System.Diagnostics TraceSource.

Comment: Try calling the `SourceTrace.TraceVerbose` method two times sequentially. I bet that occasionally you'll observe a similar time difference at the log records of the two invocations.

Comment: Okay guys to verify if SourceTrace.TraceVerbose is adding this delay, I have added one more line of SourceTrace.TraceVerbose just below "OnTimerElapsed : started" in the same method as suggested by @Theodor. I will share the result soon. Thanks!

Comment: I hope that the `SourceTrace.TraceVerbose` is the culprit, otherwise we will have to reconsider our assumptions about how async methods work. :-)

Comment: You can use [PerfView](https://github.com/microsoft/perfview) to see what's going on.